# ¿Qué me falta en mi código? similitud de textos en python

Tags: python, texto

hay algo mal aquí porque cuando pongo el código en la plataforma de calificación de la universidad, en el siguiente ejemplo dice que es incorrecto:

Si la implementación es difícil de explicar, es una mala idea.

Si la implementación es fácil de explicar, puede que sea una buena idea.

la salida es correcta debería ser:

común: 8
diferente: 7

pero mi código dice:

común: 9
diferente:7

¿Qué error estoy cometiendo?

```
Listado_a = input() 
Listado_b = input()


comun = 0 
dif = 0 
for palabra in Listado_a.split(): 
  if palabra in Listado_b.split(): 
    comun += 1 
  else: 
      dif +=1

for palabra in Listado_b.split(): 
  if palabra not in Listado_a.split(): 
    dif += 1

print(comun) 
print(dif)
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que cada palabra solo se cuenta como común una vez.

```
txt1 = 'Si la implementación es difícil de explicar, es una mala idea'
txt2 = 'Si la implementación es fácil de explicar, puede que sea una buena idea'

comun, i = 0, 0

while True:
    p = txt1.split()[i]
    if p in txt2:
        txt1 = txt1.replace(p, '')
        txt2 = txt2.replace(p, '')
        comun += 1
    else:
        i += 1
    if i >= len(txt1.split()):
        break

dif = len(txt1.split()) + len(txt2.split())

print(comun)
print(dif)
```

Tras cada aparición de una palabra la borro en los dos textos.
Las palabras diferentes son las que quedan en los textos.

Answer (score 0):

hice algo parecido en su dia y no se que tienen las listas para darte una solución acertada pero espero que esto te ayude a darte la idea.

```
Listado_a = input() 
Listado_b = input()


comun = 0 
dif = 0 
for palabra in Listado_a.split(): 
coincidencia = palabra
for palabranueva in Listado_b.split():
if palabra in Listado_b.split(): 
   comun += 1 
else: 
    dif +=1


 print(comun) 
 print(dif)
```

Comment: Gracias Kaneda, pero no me funciono, este da 13 y 0.

Comment: prueba ahora le he cambiado el nombre de lo que contiene el segundo for, entiendo que así tendria que funcionar. Gracias a ti.